# Running SQL query through RStudio via RODBC: How do I deal with Hash Tables?

Tags: sql, r, hashtable, rodbc

I've got a very basic SQL query that I'd like to be able to view in R.

The trouble is, I need to be able to reference a #table:

```
    select
    RAND(1) as random
    into #test

    select * from #test
```

Is this possible, or will I need to create permanent tables, or find some other work around?

I currently do this via a RODBC script which allows me to choose which SQL file to run:

```
    require(RODBC)
    sql.filename <- choose.files('T:\\*.*')
    sqlconn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVER_NAME;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    file.content <- readLines(sql.filename)
    output <- sqlQuery(sqlconn, paste(file.content[file.content!='--'],collapse=' '))
    closeAllConnections()
```

Do you have any advice on how I can utilise #tables in my SQL scrips in R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing your SQL query as a character string? `(x <- "#tralala")`.

Comment: The paste function creates the string. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: `paste("#", "tralala", sep = "")`. You "tralala" can also be a variable. See `?paste` or `help(paste)`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Have you tried running one sql command at a time?

Comment: I think the paste is just putting all the lines together from the sql query...after it has been read in with `readLines`....

Comment: No errors occur, but the output doesn't contain any data

Answer (score 2):

When you use temp tables SQL outputs a message with the number of rows in the table.  R doesn't know what to do with this message.  If you begin your SQL query with `SET NOCOUNT ON` SQL will not output the count message.

Answer (score 0):

I use #tables by separating my query into two parts, it returns character(0) if I do like:

```
sqlQuery(test_conn, paste("
drop table #test;
select
       RAND(1) as random
     into #test

select * from #test
"))
```

So instead I would use:

```
sqlQuery(test_conn, paste("
drop table #test;
select
       RAND(1) as random
    into #test
"))

sqlQuery(test_conn,"select * from #test")
```

It seems to work fine if you send one Query to make the #table, and a second to retrieve the contents. I also added in drop table #test; to my query, this makes sure there is not already a #test. If you try to write to a #table name that is already there you will get an error